# PHP, MySQL - Get multiple, identifiable, rows returned from a single JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo

I have three tables, something like:

```
*table1*

id | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5
 1 |  ... |  ... |  ... |  ... |  ...
 2 |  ... |  ... |  ... |  ... |  ...
 3 |  ... |  ... |  ... |  ... |  ...
... etc
```

and

```
*table2*

id | som1 | som2 
 1 |  ... |  ... 
 2 |  ... |  ... 
 3 |  ... |  ... 
... etc
```

and

```
*table3*

id | col1 | col2 
 1 |  ... |  ... 
 2 |  ... |  ... 
 3 |  ... |  ... 
... etc
```

where `col2` in the third table will *always* contain a single value from `val3`, `val4` or `val5` from the first table. The second table is only included in the question for completeness, and is not the issue.

The query I have is the following:

```
$db = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT t2.som1 AS t2som1,
                             t1.val1 AS t1v1,
                             t1.val2 AS t1v2,
                             t1.val3 AS t1v3,
                             t1.val4 AS t1v4,
                             t1.val5 AS t1v5,
                             t3.col1 AS t3col1
                        FROM table1 t1
                          JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.val2 = t2.som2
                          JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.val3 = t3.col2
                        WHERE (t1.val4=:input OR t1.val5=:input) 
                        AND (t1.val1=1 OR t1.val1=2)");

$stmt->execute(array('input'=>$inputVal));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

And this works a treat, exactly as expected.

BUT!

I don't *only* need `t3col1` for `t1.val3 = t3.col2`. I also need it for `t1.val4 = t3.col2` and `t1.val5 = t3.col2`

I can construct the line:

```
JOIN table3 t3 ON (t1.val3 = t3.col2 OR t1.val4 = t3.col2 OR t1.val5 = t3.col2)
```

But then I don't know *which value* was used to get `t3col1`. And it only returns a single value, instead of all three.

See my problem!?

I'd like to have

```
SELECT t2.som1 AS t2som1,
        ...
        t3.col1 AS t3col1, // for condition t1.val3 = t3.col2
        t3.col1 AS t3col2, // for condition t1.val4 = t3.col2
        t3.col1 AS t3col3  // for condition t1.val5 = t3.col2
```

Can this be done?

**clarification**

IF `val1`, `val2` and `val3` all contain values, I would like a *single* row returned, with all three matches from table3. NOT three separate rows, that are all identical except for the match column.

[This SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72835/16) is an example of what I *DO NOT* want. Notice that everything is identical, except for the `t3col1` columns. This should be a single row, with all the `t3col1` values.

**/clarification**

I reckon I can JOIN the table three separate times:

```
SELECT t2.som1 AS t2som1,
        ...
        t3.col1 AS t3col1
        t4.col1 AS t3col2
        t5.col1 AS t3col3
FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.val2 = t2.som2
  JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.val3 = t3.col2 // for condition t1.val3 = t3.col2
  JOIN table3 t4 ON t1.val4 = t3.col2 // for condition t1.val4 = t3.col2
  JOIN table3 t5 ON t1.val5 = t3.col2 // for condition t1.val5 = t3.col2
WHERE (...) 
AND (...)
```

but do I lose performance doing it this way (i.e. 4 JOINS), opposed to how I am trying to do it, with just the 2?

**Bonus!**

*Sometimes* `val3`, `val4` and/or `val5` will be empty (but `col2` is *never* empty). Do all the table3 JOINs need to be `LEFT JOIN`s, for those cases with empty values?

**EDIT 1**

As per your requests, I've set it up in SQLFiddle, but the service is hit-and-miss.

You can find it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72835/6)

**EDIT 2**

I tried joining table3 multiple times:

```
SELECT t2.som1 AS t2som1,
        ...
        t3.col1 AS t3col1
        t4.col1 AS t3col2
        t5.col1 AS t3col3
FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.val2 = t2.som2
  JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.val3 = t3.col2 // for condition t1.val3 = t3.col2
  JOIN table3 t4 ON t1.val4 = t3.col2 // for condition t1.val4 = t3.col2
  JOIN table3 t5 ON t1.val5 = t3.col2 // for condition t1.val5 = t3.col2
WHERE (...) 
AND (...)
```

and ended up getting a row for each match. I should have had 7 results, and ended up getting more than 90.

`val1` will always have a value, and whether `val2` and `val3` are populated is different every time. But when all three have values, I don't want three separate returns for it. Instead, I just want the one return with all three matches in it.

**EDIT 4 (The clarification was 3...)**

The *multiple JOINs* from EDIT 2 was what ended up working, thanks to Siraj's answer. The problem was that I used:

```
JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.val3 = t3.col2 
JOIN table3 t4 ON t1.val4 = t3.col2 
JOIN table3 t5 ON t1.val5 = t3.col2
```

when I should have used:

```
JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.val3 = t3.col2 
JOIN table3 t4 ON t1.val4 = t4.col2 
JOIN table3 t5 ON t1.val5 = t5.col2
```

Notice the difference? It's just the `t3.col2` after each equal sign - they need to reference the correct table! The rest all stays the same, and Bob's your auntie!

Comment: You can construct your query using Cases which can tell you which value was used for join in your first query.

Comment: Provide SQL Fiddle for your sample data then it would be easy to answer.

Comment: Remember, if this is an `InnoDB` table, the fields that are primary key and foreign keys must be defined *first* in the table schema.

Comment: can't you just select t3.col2 as well, or am I missing the problem?

Comment: @EggVans, I could select it if only *one* value for `t3.col1` was returned. But I need up to three matches returned, ideally in the same row.

Comment: @SirajulHaq the fiddle is working now - link in EDIT1. Can't say how long it'll last, get it while it's hot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below query will give you the data as you wanted:

```
SELECT t2.som1 AS t2som1,
 t1.val1 AS t1v1,
 t1.val2 AS t1v2,
 t1.val3 AS t1v3,
 t1.val4 AS t1v4,
 t1.val5 AS t1v5,
 t3.col1 AS t3col1,
 t3.col2 AS t3col2,
 CASE WHEN t1.val3 = t3.col2 THEN t3.col1 ELSE '' END AS 't3col11',
 CASE WHEN t1.val4 = t3.col2 THEN t3.col1 ELSE '' END AS 't3col21',
 CASE WHEN t1.val5 = t3.col2 THEN t3.col1 ELSE '' END AS 't3col31',
 CASE WHEN t1.val3 = t3.col2 THEN 't1col3'
 ELSE CASE WHEN t1.val4 = t3.col2 THEN 't1col4' ELSE 't1col5'
 END END AS ColumnName
FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.val2 = t2.som2
  JOIN table3 t3 ON (t1.val3 = t3.col2 OR t1.val4 = t3.col2 OR t1.val5 = t3.col2)
GROUP BY t2som1,t1v1, t1v2, t1v3, t1v4, t1v5
```

The last column that is 'ColumnName' tells you which t1 column was the one that matches the value.

**Edit - Using left join**

```
SELECT t2.som1 AS t2som1,
t1.val1 AS t1v1,
t1.val2 AS t1v2,
t1.val3 AS t1v3,
t1.val4 AS t1v4,
t1.val5 AS t1v5,
t3.col1 AS t3col1,
    t3.col1 AS t3col1,
    t4.col1 AS t3col2,
    t5.col1 AS t3col3
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.val2 = t2.som2
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.val3 = t3.col2
LEFT JOIN table3 t4 ON t1.val4 = t4.col2
LEFT JOIN table3 t5 ON t1.val5 = t5.col2
```

Comment: This gives me, potentially, three times as many results as I want. I'm running it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72835/11) with what you've given, and you'll see that the first (1st), seventh (7th) and twelfth (12th) rows returned are identical, save for the `t3col1` values. I need these condensed into a single row, with all three `t3col1` columns filled.

Comment: I've added a "clarification" section to the original post, describing what I would like returned.

Comment: Are you asking me? I've never used either. Fix your answer, since it's not what I'm asking for, and use either of what you just said. If it works, I give you the selected answer..

Comment: @Birrel i have improved the query and you will see 6 rows now

Comment: yes, but in more than one of those rows, `t3col21` and/or `t3col31` should also contain values. Mine are all empty [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72835/22)... Basically, if there is something in `val3`, then `t3col11` should have something. If `val4` has something, then so should `t3col21`. And `val5` and `t3col31`.

Comment: its because you are joining in this sequence (t1.val3 = t3.col2 OR t1.val4 = t3.col2 OR t1.val5 = t3.col2) and your column t1.val3 matches t3.col2 for every record, try inserting unique data in other columns that matches to that column only.

Comment: if you see this line CASE WHEN t1.val3 = t3.col2 THEN t3.col1 ELSE '' END AS 't3col11', it tells you if t1.val3 = t3.col2 then it will show you t3.col1 other wise it will give you ELSE ''. Replace what ever you want to show in else statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110941/discussion-between-birrel-and-siraj-ul-haq).